# How to create multiple Databases on Amazon RDS Aurora?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I am new to AWS. I have a confusion which I want to figure out. My question is: **Can we create multiple databases on a single Amazon RDS Aurora DB Instance?** by simply connecting to the database engine using root credentials and querying `"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS"` command?

Hope I am much clear about my question. Further, Please guide if there is any other option to achive defined functionality.

**TIA.**

Comment: Yes, you use SQL for that once you login to the instance. Any issues with that?

Comment: You may use the RDS as a normal DB server, creating different users and databases. Just try it

Comment: @Marcin can you please share some useful link? From where i can get an idea as how we can do that?

Comment: MySQL and PostgreSQL documantions are good starts.

Comment: @gusto2 Thank you very much! Can you please share any link?

Comment: Ah Thank you @Marcin. You saved my day

Comment: I mean - just Google it. Or where is the problem? You cannot connect to the RDS? You don't know the syntax? You can choose the aurora to behave as MySQL or Postgres

Comment: I also noticed that almost all your questions have answers, yet not a single one accepted. Accepting good answers is not only a good practice, but it reduces number of duplicates and increases chances for your questions to be actually answered.

Comment: @gusto2, Well I haven't started playing with that yet! but that would be awesome if you can please share the syntax to connect to RDS Instance and CRUD Demo

Comment: @Marcin, Sincere Apologies, I did not get you? As of my questions, I looked for Stackoverflow other questions but none of them satisfied me. hence, created a new one.

Comment: I mean that you asked lots of questions, https://stackoverflow.com/users/12525976/asad-mehmood?tab=questions, and got answers. Yet, you haven't accepted any single one of them. Can you confirm that all of them, not even a single answer, wasn't helpful?

Comment: @Marcin, Apology once again, The answers which helped me resolve my issue. I upvoted them but did not know how to accpet one? Am i supposed to accept?

Comment: Yes. You can revisit the answers and click a "tick" like button under up/down-vote buttons to accept the answer. This way, your question gets marked as resolved and helps others.

Comment: @Marcin, Thanks! I will surely go for it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the comments.

You create extra databases using SQL. Once you connect to your Aurora RDS, either MySQL or PostgreSQL, using `mysql` or `psql` clients (or other client), you can **use SQL to create new databases**:

- MySQL: [CREATE DATABASE Statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html)
- PostgreSQL: [CREATE DATABASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-createdatabase.html)